# Reports API 503 Backend Error

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, google-admin-sdk

For the past couple of weeks the batch task I use to retrieve User Usage Reports from the Reports API has been failing with the following response:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 OK
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Backend Error",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  }],
  "message" : "Backend Error"
}
```

Is anyone else seeing this error? Seems like an internal error on the API. Is there anything I can do on my end to avoid this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I have this error as well, and nothing to do with quota.. Did you find the solution already?

Comment: Could share which API call is causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

you have this error beacause Project Number (Sender ID) is not found or deleted. Create the news project in https://console.developers.google.com/project and test with this url :https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project= Project Number

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was having a 503 in my backend when i had an endpoint query. 
when you are using google datastore first you have to run it on localhost so it would create the index in a file called datastore-indexes-auto.xml
this is automaticaly generated.

this is an index example

```
<!-- Used 1 time in query history -->
<datastore-index kind="Conference" ancestor="true" source="auto">
    <property name="name" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Comment: hi... while you were getting a 503, it is possible that you may have got it for a different reason from the question asker... could you clarify how you are inferring that the error you got is related to the question, perhaps by posting further details of the error...